# Sublime Editor Tree View

Tags: javascript, python, json, sublimetext2

Is it possible to create a tree view for arbitrary data (JSON) as a plugin for Sublime Editor. I like working with javascript, and don't like having to switch to my firefox console to inspect objects.

Is there an existing plugin/solution?
Is it possible for me to make my own - can a tree view be displayed in Sublime Editor easily?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about tree-views but with jsFormat you can get a nice format of the json-object, basically a pretty-print.

The if you'd like to get advanced, and your JSON contains a lot of objects you can always use code-folding. Although this doesn't work very well with arrays (it will fold the complete json for me atleast).